# mail php send 500 on console

Tags: php, forms, email

i have form on this page http://cp34532-wordpress-76.tw1.ru/?dt_courses=professionalnyj-microsoft-office-excel

when i insert all data, then click submit it giving me alert about filed saved.

and on console error 500

this is code:

```
<?php

  if(!$_POST) exit;

  $to     = $_POST['hid_adminemail']; #Replace your email id...
  $dtfullname   = utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['dtfullname']));
  $dtemail    = $_POST['dtemail'];
  $dtcourse    = utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['dtcourse']));
  $subject  = $_POST['hid_subject'];
  $dtdatetimepicker  = isset($_POST['dtdatetimepicker']) ? $_POST['dtdatetimepicker'] : '';

  if($dtfullname == '' || $dtemail == '') :   
    echo "<span class='error-msg'>".__('Заполните поля', 'lms')."</span>";
    exit;
  endif;

  $e_subject = $subject;

  $msg  = $dtfullname. ' has been subscribed for '.$dtcourse.'\r\n\n';
  if($dtdatetimepicker != '')
    $msg  .= 'He/She planned to visit in person on '.$dtdatetimepicker.'\r\n\n';
  $msg .= "You can contact $dtfullname via email, $dtemail.\r\n\n";
  $msg .= "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

  if(wp_mail($to, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $dtemail\r\nReturn-Path: $dtemail\r\n"))
  {
    echo "<span class='success-msg'>".$_POST['hid_successmsg']."</span>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<span class='error-msg'>".$_POST['hid_errormsg']."</span>";
  }

?>
```

so can u give your quote where is problem

and again i have check the hosting is work well.

Comment: The very first thing you _always_ do on a 500, is check the server’s error log …

Comment: @misorude where i can see it bro?

Comment: Depends on your server & setup. Go check your hoster’s documentation/FAQ.